# Reading xml ref attribute in .NET

Tags: c#, xml, dom

I can do this in Xpath, but unfortunately for this particular project I am unable to use xpath.

I have the following node selected:

```
<client href="http://somewebsitehere.com" rel="needthisdata"></client>


clientnode.Attributes["href"].Value
```

correctly returns "http://somewebsitehere.com", but

```
clientnode.Attributes["rel"].Value
```

does not work?

What am I doing wrong here?

Full Usage:

```
foreach (XmlNode clientnode in clientnodelist)
{
    MessageBox.Show(clientnode.Attributes["rel"].Value);
}
```

The above gives a NullReferenceException, whereas replacing "rel" with "href" works fine.

I'm sure i've selected the correct node as well as innertext matches, as well as attribute.count returning 2.

Comment: How exectly it is not working? You receive exception or it returns some wrong value?

Comment: Is the `<client></link>` line correct?

Comment: Updated original post for further clarification

Comment: Is this single node of <client> node? Or you have other among clientnodelist? If so then may be you really don't have 'rel' attribute for one of the nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your code. You are using `clientnode` as the loop variable, but you are referencing `selectednode`.

---

What if one particular node doesn't have a "rel" attribute? `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: sorry, it was a bad copy/paste job! fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I would add a break at the loop and take a look at what is in my Attributes collection. Also, for kicks, try changing "rel" to something else to see if it fixes the issue.